# YouTube Content ID API with Service Account returns Forbidden error

Tags: php, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I've created a service account for use with the YouTube Content ID API, I'm following the steps under **Set up your service account** on:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/guides/oauth2_for_service_accounts

The steps seem to be a bit outdated, but I'm managed to create a service account and I've got the email address. I didn't know if I needed to assign a Role so I didn't.

I visited the Content ID users page and invited the service account user:

[image]

The problem is I get the error `the request could not be completed`, but when I refresh the page, the user appears to be added successfully.

Well, when I'm making requests using this service account, I'm getting forbidden errors. For example the below error is when I'm trying to get a list of claims.

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "forbidden",
"message": "Forbidden"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "Forbidden"
}
}
```

But some requests work, like listing/inserting labels, listing content owners.

All the permissions are assigned for the user so I'm not sure what the reason for the forbidden errors are.

Here's the PHP code:

```
$OAUTH2_KEY_FILE = 'key.json';

$client = new \Google_Client();

$client->setAuthConfig($OAUTH2_KEY_FILE);
$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_YouTubePartner::YOUTUBEPARTNER]);
$youtubePartner = new \Google_Service_YouTubePartner($client);

dd($youtubePartner->claims->listClaims([
    'onBehalfOfContentOwner' => 'XXX'
]));
```

Comment: When you visit the [documentation specifically to the errors page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors), you will find out that the reason of [forbidden](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#general-errors) errors could be the improper authorization of request. Try to find what is the specific error and check there.

Comment: I’m aware that forbidden means it’s not authorised. I’m trying to figure out why it’s not authorised. That’s the problem.

Comment: @Wasim, I got the same error. Did you find any answers yet?

Comment: @searain Still waiting on YouTube CID support to get back to me about it.

Comment: @Wasim A few months ago, the service accounts cannot be added at all. even after you refresh pages, the accounts were not added. Now, the accounts can be added (even with error but after refresh page, it is added) but like list claims methods etc still give the 403 error.